# AWS Lambda Python package - no module named redis

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have a `python` package that I would like to upload to `AWS Lambda`.
The package works on two different machines with no dependencies issues at all.

However, when uploading the same folder to `AWS Lambda`, I get the following error:

> Unable to import module 'tweet_analyzer_python/lambda_handler': No module named redis

Here is a list of the files in the package:

```
.
|-- event.json
|-- lambda_handler.py
|-- redis
|   |-- client.py
|   |-- client.pyc
|   |-- _compat.py
|   |-- _compat.pyc
|   |-- connection.py
|   |-- connection.pyc
|   |-- exceptions.py
|   |-- exceptions.pyc
|   |-- __init__.py
|   |-- __init__.pyc
|   |-- lock.py
|   |-- lock.pyc
|   |-- sentinel.py
|   |-- utils.py
|   `-- utils.pyc
|-- redis-2.10.5-py2.7.egg-info
|   |-- dependency_links.txt
|   |-- installed-files.txt
|   |-- PKG-INFO
|   |-- SOURCES.txt
|   `-- top_level.txt
|-- retrying-1.3.3-py2.7.egg-info
|   |-- dependency_links.txt
|   |-- installed-files.txt
|   |-- PKG-INFO
|   |-- requires.txt
|   |-- SOURCES.txt
|   `-- top_level.txt
|-- retrying.py
|-- retrying.pyc
|-- six-1.10.0-py2.7.egg-info
|   |-- dependency_links.txt
|   |-- installed-files.txt
|   |-- PKG-INFO
|   |-- SOURCES.txt
|   `-- top_level.txt
|-- six.py
`-- six.pyc
```

For double-checking, I have downloaded the same `zip` file that was uploaded to `AWS Lambda` and put it on a clean linux machine. 
When running:

> python tweet_analyzer_python/lambda_handler

I had no issues at all.

Can someone explain me what am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run 'lambda_handler.py' locally you are running a main methods within the python file. The lambda function however calls the lambda_handler method within lambda_handler.py directly.

Your lambda handler is not configured to run 'lambda_handler.lambda_handler' and is failing on 'tweet_analyzer_python/lambda_handler'

Either :

- 1) rename lambda_handler.py to tweet_analyzer_python or
- 2) change your lambda handler to 'lambda_handler.lambda_handler'

To change your handler; go your lambda in AWS, select configuration, and update the handler and save the function.

Also ensure your redis dep is packaged in your zipped lambda function.